# какие библиотеки в python можно использовать для получения информации о пополнениях qiwi кошелька?

Tags: python, qiwi, pyqiwi

Пишу бота который должен проверять информацию с пополнения и сравнивать комментарий и сумму пополнения с выставленным счетом

Answer (score 1):

API для доступа к ресурсам QIWI, как и большинство подобных API, просто соглашение о формировании HTTP запросов.

[Описание QIWI API](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#intro)

Поэтому Вы можете использовать **любую** из множества Python библиотек, предназначенных для работы с HTTP запросами. Первое, что приходит в голову:

[Requests в Python – Примеры выполнения HTTP запросов](https://python-scripts.com/requests)